# how to disabled site-isolation in chrome thast version after 72.0

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, security

I want disabled site-isolation in chrome so that I can see the cookie in request header easily.I Starting Chrome with the --disable-site-isolation-trials in the past.But when chrome version after 72.It becomes useless.How I can do in the newest chrome

Answer (score 1):

Open `chrome://flags/#enable-site-per-process` and search for **"Disable site isolation"**. 
If you're confident with Google and want to get more comprehensive guarantee, just choose **Default**.

Comment: i can not find #enable-site-per-process  in chrome 76
do you konw how chrome works?

Answer (score 0):

Current version (Chrome 75) crashes when switching flag `Disable site isolation` to `disabled`, relaunch browser and open developer tools (aka. inspect).